# Is there something like a scope of \NewDocumentCommand?

Tags: latex3, expl3, xparse

Following along the line of [my (confused) post on xparse and expl3](/questions/129721/dazzled-and-confused-about-xparse-and-latex3-booleans), but this time hopefully with no typos or missing characters, I've devised a small package just to check a `l3keys`-based definition and setting of options. My issue is not (so far) with the passing of options, but with an unexpected (to me) behavior of a command.

I have a file `tmpkgl3.sty` with this content:

```
\ProvidesPackage{tmpkgl3}[2013/08/20 LaTeX2e/LaTeX3 wannabe package]

\RequirePackage{xparse,l3keys2e} 

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Some of the variants are already declared in LaTeX3
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \bool_new:N {c}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \bool_if:NTF {cTF}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \bool_set_true:N {c}

% I have in mind egreg's remarks in my linked post regarding not using this as I do.
\tl_const:Nn \c_prefix_tl {g_amod_} 
\tl_const:Nn \c_postfix_tl {_bool} 

\NewDocumentCommand\MakeBool { m }
 { 
   \bool_new:c 
   { \tl_use:N \c_prefix_tl #1 \tl_use:N \c_postfix_tl }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand\SetTBool { m } 
 {
   \bool_set_true:c
   { \tl_use:N \c_prefix_tl #1 \tl_use:N \c_postfix_tl }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand\WelcherWegBool { m m m } 
 { 
    \bool_if:cTF 
    { \tl_use:N \c_prefix_tl #1 \tl_use:N \c_postfix_tl } 
    { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\MakeBool{esp}

\keys_define:nn { amod }
{
    lang .choice_code:n =
        { \SetTBool { \tl_use:N \l_keys_choice_tl } 
           \WelcherWegBool { esp } { True } { False } \par
        },
    lang .generate_choices:n = { esp },
}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\DocumentSetup { +m }
 { \keys_set:nn { amod } { #1 } }

%\ProcessKeysOptions { amod }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Then, I have the next content in a .tex file `l3tryout.tex`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{tmpkgl3}

%\ExplSyntaxOn

%\ProvideDocumentCommand\WelcherWegBool { m m m } 
% { 
%    \bool_if:cTF 
%    { \tl_use:N \c_prefix_tl  #1  \tl_use:N \c_postfix_tl } 
%    { #2 } { #3 }
% }

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \DocumentSetup{ lang = esp } 
}

\begin{document}
\WelcherWegBool { esp } { T } { F }
\end{document}

%\ExplSyntaxOff
```

With the files like above I get `True F`, whereas I should get `True T` (in two different paragraphs due to the `\par` in the options definition). Nonetheless, if I uncomment the commented lines in the `l3tryout.tex` file, I get the right result. It's as though the command `\WelcherWegBool` worked fine in the package but not so in the tex file. May this have something to do with having switched off the `ExplSyntax` switch?

Comment: In the scope of `\ExplSyntaxOn`, `{esp}` and `{ esp }` are equivalent; they aren't in normal text.

Comment: @egreg: Right, I guess you're talking about my ``\MakeBool{esp}`` line. I was aware, but does it change anything? Maybe the title for my post has not been fortunate and may lead to confusion?

Comment: @egreg: Oh, ok, I guess I got your point now... I need to be careful about the spaces when I'm not in the scope of the ``ExplSyntax`` switch. I'll check this right now... but it might be the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the scope of `\ExplSyntaxOn`, `{esp}` and `{ esp }` as argument to a function are equivalent. They aren't in a normal document where spaces are not ignored.

If you really want to allow

```
\WelcherWegBool { esp } { T }{ F }
```

in the document, then you have to use `\tl_trim_spaces:n { #1 }` in the definitions:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xparse,l3keys2e} 

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Some of the variants are already declared in LaTeX3
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \bool_new:N {c}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \bool_if:NTF {cTF}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \bool_set_true:N {c}

% I have in mind egreg's remarks in my linked post regarding not using this as I do.
\tl_const:Nn \c_prefix_tl {g_amod_} 
\tl_const:Nn \c_postfix_tl {_bool} 

\NewDocumentCommand\MakeBool { m }
 { 
   \bool_new:c 
   { \tl_use:N \c_prefix_tl \tl_trim_spaces:n{ #1 } \tl_use:N \c_postfix_tl }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand\SetTBool { m } 
 {
   \bool_set_true:c
   { \tl_use:N \c_prefix_tl \tl_trim_spaces:n { #1 } \tl_use:N \c_postfix_tl }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand\WelcherWegBool { m m m } 
 { 
    \bool_if:cTF 
    { \tl_use:N \c_prefix_tl  \tl_trim_spaces:n { #1 }  \tl_use:N \c_postfix_tl } 
    { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\MakeBool{esp}

\keys_define:nn { amod }
{
    lang .choice_code:n =
        { \SetTBool { \tl_use:N \l_keys_choice_tl } 
           \WelcherWegBool { esp } { True } { False } \par
        },
    lang .generate_choices:n = { esp },
}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\DocumentSetup { +m }
 { \keys_set:nn { amod }{#1} }

%\ProcessKeysOptions { amod }

\ExplSyntaxOff 

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \DocumentSetup{ lang = esp } 
}

\begin{document}
\WelcherWegBool { esp } { T }{ F }
\end{document}
```

Of course, spaces will *not* be ignored around `T` and `F` (although they can be removed by TeX's typesetting rules).

Comment: That made it... and besides I gained significant understanding on the importance of the ``\tl_trim_spaces:n`` function.